# Write a function that reads line by line from the console and prints the number of characters for each line loaded

Tags: c, char, fgets, c-strings, counting

Write a function that reads line by line from the console and prints the number of characters for each line loaded, The maximum length of the line being read should be 20 characters.

I have someting that just goes throught loop and print over and over to input string.
I'm having problem with - Print number of characters after each user input and set max character input to 20 for exampe. Someone to help me?

```
     char str[str_size];
    int alp, digit, splch, i;
    alp = digit = splch = i = 0;


    printf("\n\nCount total number of alphabets, digits and special characters :\n");
    printf("--------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
    do {
        printf("Input the string : ");

        fgets(str, sizeof str, stdin);

    } while (str[i] != '\0');
        if ((str[i] >= 'a' && str[i] <= 'z') || (str[i] >= 'A' && str[i] <= 'Z'))
        {
            alp++;

        }
        else if (str[i] >= '0' && str[i] <= '9')
        {
            digit++;
        }
        else
        {
            splch++;
        }

        i++;

printf("Number of Alphabets in the string is : %d\n", alp + digit + splch);


}
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand what you do with `do while` loop in your code. So i just propose another loop for your case. I'm not sure but hope that code is what you want.

```
int main() {
    char str[22];
    int alp, digit, splch, i;
    printf("\n\nCount total number of alphabets, digits and special characters :\n");
    printf("--------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
    printf("Input the string : ");
    while (fgets(str, sizeof str, stdin)){
        alp = digit = splch = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++ ) {
            if ((str[i] >= 'a' && str[i] <= 'z') || (str[i] >= 'A' && str[i] <= 'Z'))
            {
                alp++;
            }
            else if (str[i] >= '0' && str[i] <= '9')
            {
                digit++;
            }
            else if(str[i] != '\n')
            {
                splch++;
            }
        }
        printf("alp = %d, digit = %d, splch = %d\n", alp, digit, splch);
        printf("Input the string : ");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

OT, for determine the alpha or digit, you can use `isdigit()` and `isalpha()` functions. It's more simple than something you used in your code.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the program can look the following way

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) 
{
    enum { str_size = 22 };
    char str[str_size];

    puts( "\nCount total number of alphabets, digits and special characters");
    puts( "--------------------------------------------------------------");

    while ( 1 )
    {
        printf( "\nInput a string less than or equal to %d characters (Enter - exit): ",
                str_size - 2 );

        if ( fgets( str, str_size, stdin ) == NULL || str[0] == '\n' ) break;

        unsigned int alpha = 0, digit = 0, special = 0;

        // removing the appended new line character by fgets
        str[ strcspn( str, "\n" ) ] = '\0';

        for ( const char *p = str; *p != '\0'; ++p )
        {
            unsigned char c = *p;

            if ( isalpha( c ) ) ++alpha;
            else if ( isdigit( c ) ) ++digit;
            else ++special;
        }

        printf( "\nThere are %u letters, %u digits and %u special characters in the string\n",
                alpha, digit, special );    
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The program output might look like

```
Count total number of alphabets, digits and special characters
--------------------------------------------------------------

Input a string less than or equal to 20 characters (Enter - exit): April, 22, 2020

There are 5 letters, 6 digits and 4 special characters in the string

Input a string less than or equal to 20 characters (Enter - exit):
```

If the user will just press the Enter key the loop will finish.

Pay attention to that the program considers white space and  punctuation characters as special characters.